# Can Chrome have more than 2 Cookie Stores (Normal and Incognito)

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

According to following API from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies,

> ### `getAllCookieStores`
>
> `chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores(function callback)`
>   Lists all existing cookie stores.

It returns an array of Cookie Stores. From my experimentation, I can see that all normal windows constitute one cookie store and all Incognito windows constitute another cookie store.

Is there a scenario where there may be more than 2 cookie stores in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/cookies/cookies_api.cc?l=530&rcl=8c187aca591375ac9e0b795d497b3f2ccfe2b6cf) there are only two stores: normal and incognito. `getAllCookieStores` result depends on which tabs are currently open (none, normal and/or incognito) so it may return 0, 1, or 2 stores.

Comment: Thanks! Kudos for the source link!